# Two questions on Serrin's "A symmetry problem in potential theory"

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Since it would be unfeasible to describe the whole context of the problems, I seek help from people familiar with the Moving Plane Method and the paper

> Serrin, J. A symmetry problem in potential theory. Arch. Rational Mech. Anal. 43, 304–318 (1971). https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00250468.

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain of $\mathbb R^N$ with boundary of class $C^2$ and $H_0$ a hyperplane far away from $\Omega$. Start moving the plane in an orthogonal direction until it starts intersecting $\Omega$, and denote the plane at the new position by $H$. It defines a cap, that is the part of $\Omega$ at the same side of $H$ as $H_0$.

> How can we justify that the reflection of the cap stays inside $\Omega$ in the beginning?

I think that it is because of the inner ball condition, that holds since $\partial \Omega$ is $C^2$: in the beginning, we are reflecting small pieces of the balls, which lay inside the balls themselves, and hence inside $\Omega$. Is this correct? Is there a more analytical argument?

In second place, on 308 the author claims that since the reflected cap $\Sigma'$ lies inside $\Omega$,
$$
\phi_{1l} = 0 \quad \text{ at} \quad Q, \qquad l = 2, \ldots, n - 1,
$$
where $\phi$ is the $C^2$ function that describes the boundary of the domain $\Omega$ near the point $Q$ where the critical plane is orthogonal to $\partial \Omega$.

I think that this can be translated as follows: consider a function $\phi$ in a bounded domain of $\mathbb R^{N - 1}$ containing the origin such that $\phi(0) = 0$ and $\phi$ attains a local minimum at $0$. Assume also that $\phi(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{N - 1}) \leq \phi(-x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{N - 1})$. Then $f_{1l}(0) = 0$, for $2 \leq l \leq N -1$.

> Why is it true?

I have been thinking about this for days, but couldn't find any argument nor obtain any intuition.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

What about this attempt for the second question:

We know that $\phi_1(0) = 0$. If $\phi_{1j}(0) \neq 0$, then we would have $\phi_1$ positive at some side of the origin. This would mean that $\phi$ is increasing at some point $(0, \hat x_2, \ldots, \hat x_{N - 1})$ in the direction of $x_1$, which is absurd, because in such case we would have $\phi(-x_1, \hat x_2, \ldots, \hat x_{N - 1}) < \phi(x_1, \hat x_2, \ldots, \hat x_{N - 1})$, which contradicts the fact that the reflection lies inside $\Omega$.

Comment: Would you like to be more specific about the context, and make your question more self-contained?

Comment: Dear Lee, I will try to add more detail on the first question, but for the second it would amount to provide a theorem and almost the entire proof, which is not short. I will try to go to the core of the question, but I'm not really sure that I will succeed

Comment: The clearer your question, the better your odds at getting a satisfactory answer. You still use some notation without defining it. Presumably $H$ is the parallel copy of $H_0$ that intersects $\Omega$? Also, what is the function $f$?

Comment: Sorry, $f$ should be $\phi$. And I indeed forgot to define $H$, I'm sorry

Comment: Your first question has an easier answer: this is just because the boundary can be locally expressed as the graph of $\phi$. For the second question, you should try a Taylor expansion of the inequality you give, expressing $\phi(h,\dots,k,\dots,0)$ (with $h,k$ in the first and $i$th position respectively) in terms of the second partial derivatives. You can cancel everything but the mixed derivatives $D_{1i} \phi$; swapping the sign of $k$ should give you the identity you are looking for.